# Android : Network operations in Appwidget

Tags: android, networking, operations, android-appwidget

I'm developing a Android AppWidget for my application. For updating my appwidget I need to download data from network. But when I try to do that in onUpdate method, my appWidget is killed by Android system. I learnt that time consuming operations can't be done in receivers so I launched a service from onUpdate method and launched a thread from that. But still the problem persists.
Can anyone please let me know how to do network operations in Appwidget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate the download work to a service, probably an `IntentService`, possibly a [`WakefulIntentService`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) depending on whether there is a risk that the device might fall asleep during the work itself.

Your `AppWidgetProvider` would just call `startService()` on your `IntentService`.

Your `IntentService's` `onHandleIntent()` method would do the work you presently have in `onUpdate()`, getting its own `AppWidgetManager` via the static `getInstance()` method. But, since `onHandleIntent()` is executed on a background thread, you can take as much time as you need. The `IntentService` will also automatically shut down once it is done with all outstanding work requests.

Comment: but how to combine that with use of RemoteViewsService? Should mentioned IntentService start RemoteViewsService after async operation is done?

Comment: @Malachiasz: "Should mentioned IntentService start RemoteViewsService after async operation is done?" -- no. `RemoteViewsService` will be automatically used by the app widget framework. You need to make sure that the `RemoteViewsService` is aware of whatever data changes were made by the `IntentService`, such as by the `IntentService` updating a database that the `RemoteViewsService` needs to pull from. There should be a way to get the app widget to then reload its views from the `RemoteViewsService`, though I have not researched this and do not know off the top of my head how it is done.